# Pivot chart won't refresh upon opening workbook (multiple protected worksheets)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Having an issue where a pivot chart is not refreshing upon opening my file. I have a web query setup on a protected worksheet called 'DATA' and a pivot table/chart on another worksheet called 'Summary'.

I also have another sheet called 'PW' where I have the password to unlock the worksheets stored (hidden) so no one can pick up my password if they look at the code. All worksheets are protected with the same password.

I believe I need to adjust my code to unlock both worksheets but... well I can't figure it out!

This is the code I have that refreshes the web query without any issues. If someone could help me adjust it to unlock both sheets, refresh all and then protect both worksheets it'd be much appreciated :)

I'm using Excel 2016.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("DATA").Unprotect Password:=Sheets("PW").Range("K2").Value
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
Sheets("DATA").Protect _
Password:=Sheets("PW").Range("K2").Value, _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I've tried the following code to unprotect both worksheets, refresh the web query on the 'DATA' worksheet, then refresh the pivot table on the 'Summary' worksheet, then protect both sheets again. It's returning an error though... Any ideas? Sorry new to this...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("DATA", "Summary"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In sheetsArray
ws.Unprotect Password:=Sheets("PW").Range("K2").Value
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").Refresh
Sheets("Summary").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
For Each ws In sheetsArray
ws.Protect Password:=Sheets("PW").Range("K2").Value, _
Next
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: It might be that the pivot table/chart is refreshing before the table/query. In general, I advise explicitly refreshing them in the right order, with `BackgroundQuery` set to false for tables.

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for your help Doug. Please see my edit above - if you can help in any way, it'd be appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: What error are you getting, and where?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about pivot tables, but you will probably need
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

at the end of your sub to see the changes.